# Find a nontrivial solution of the initial-value problem $y'=ty^a$ $y(0)=0$ $a>1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a nontrivial solution of the initial-value problem $y'=ty^a$ $y(0)=0$ $a>1$

My attempt:
$$y'=ty^a$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ty^a$$
$$\frac{dy}{y^a}=t\,dt$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y^a}=\int t\,dt$$ 
$$\ln|y^a|=(1/2)t^2+C$$
$$e^{\ln|y^a|}=e^{(1/2)t^2+C}$$
$$y^a=Ae^{(1/2)t^2}$$ 
And we need $y(0)=0$ so

$$0^a=Ae^{(1/2)0^2}$$
$$0=A\cdot1$$

so $A=0$

But isn't this just the trivial solution? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\frac{dx}{f(x)} \ne \ln|f(x)|$ for all $f(x) \ne x$

Comment: A well known theorem due to C$____$ and L$____$ should indicate that what you ask is impossible.

Comment: @Did I think the name of P$_____$ belongs there; C$____$ is associated with existence.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat [Cultural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) [differences](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Cauchy-Lipschitz), it seems (check where the links on the left column go...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int\frac{dy}{y^a} = \begin{cases} \dfrac{y^{-a+1}}{-a+1} + C & \text{unless }a=1, \\[10pt]
\ln y + C & \text{if }a=1. \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in the way you integrate the equation, as Michael's answer shows.

However, if $a\ge1$ the right hand side of the equation satisfies the conditions of the existence and uniqueness theorem. This implies that the only solution is $y\equiv0$. If $0<a<1$, it is a different story.